# asp.net web forms [WebMethod]

Tags: asp.net, web, webforms, json.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a problem with my [WebMethod] when I return Json data `List<Contract>` from `DB` using `Entity Framework`

```
function populateData(pageIndex) {
                // populate data from database
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Pages/App/Docs.aspx/PopulateDataByJquery",
                    data: "{pageNo: " + pageIndex + ", noOfRecord: 7}",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    error: onError
                });
            }
            function OnSuccess(data) {

                alert('good');
            }
            function onError() {
                alert('Failed!');
                $('#LoadingPanel').css('display', 'none');
            }
```

This my WeMethod.

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<Contract> PopulateDataByJquery(int pageNo, int noOfRecord)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Entities4 db = new Entities4();
        List<Contract> data = new List<Contract>();
        int skip = (pageNo - 1) * noOfRecord;
        data = db.Contracts.Include("PhysicalPerson").Include("Product").OrderBy(a => a.Id).Skip(skip).Take(noOfRecord).ToList(); 
        return data;
    }
```

**I every time getting ajax error, help me please! I don't know how it fix.**

Comment: What's the ajax error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make some changes to your ajax call and `WebMethod`

```
function populateData(pageIndex) {
                    // populate data from database
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "Docs.aspx/PopulateDataByJquery",
                        data: "{pageNo: pageIndex, noOfRecord: 7}",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: OnSuccess,
                        error: onError
                    });
                }
                function OnSuccess(data) {

                    alert('good');
                }
                function onError() {
                    alert('Failed!');
                    $('#LoadingPanel').css('display', 'none');
                }
```

Change your `WebMethod`

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string  PopulateDataByJquery(int pageNo, int noOfRecord)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Entities4 db = new Entities4();
        List<Contract> data = new List<Contract>();
        int skip = (pageNo - 1) * noOfRecord;
        data = db.Contracts.Include("PhysicalPerson").Include("Product").OrderBy(a => a.Id).Skip(skip).Take(noOfRecord).ToList(); 
        JavaScriptSerializer TheSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer()
        var TheJson = TheSerializer.Serialize(data);
         // for this you need to add using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
        return TheJson;
    }
```

For more read [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

Comment: aspx page could be in directory as well as PO saying in Q.You can not call directly to method, you must have to write directory name in url

Comment: *aspx page could be in directory as well as PO saying in Q.* I have not seen anywhere, can you please explain me in brief. And Yes dear it's not `PO` it's `OP`

Comment: *I have a problem with my [WebMethod] when I **return Json** data List<Contract> from DB using Entity Framework *, His getting error while returning Json, he didnt mention anywhere like not able to call WebMethod, so dont need to change Url, Just need to return serialize  data FYI

Comment: *so dont need to change Url, Just need to return serialize data* Yes, may you're right but if you change like as i suggested, then also not getting any error.

Comment: @Div Thank you for help, I added **Serialize()** but I get error `Additional information: When you serialize an object of type "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Contract_5C6A43C0345D88A59AAF37B6A7761EEA78CCAA4A00E50985F499A031FA6EF116" revealed a circular reference.`

Comment: @Div I used **JavaScriptSerializer** but I get tighter error `Additional information: When you serialize an object of type "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Contract_5C6A43C0345D88A5‌​9AAF37B6A7761EEA78CC‌​AA4A00E50985F499A031‌​FA6EF116" revealed a circular reference.`

Comment: @Div I dont know yet, I didn't try your the link recommendation, I'll try later. If all good, I will put a mark. Thank you for your attention!